# How to get fine-grained sentiment score from text data under unsupervised learning?

Tags: nlp, lstm, text-mining, text-classification, sentiment-analysis

In my experience I have only used LSTM models to do sentiment classification tasks on text data under supervised learning. For example, the imdb dataset from keras which is a binary classification task, and sentiment140 dataset from kaggle which has three classes (0, 2 and 4).

First, I want to get sentiment scores from text data under unsupervised learning. For example, I wish to get yesterday's sentiment score from yesterday's news. If I have to label a sentiment score to every news it would be nearly impossible.

Second, I wish to get a fine-grained sentiment score rather than several classes.

Since I am only familiar with LSTM, I want to ask that which model should I use? I think the first  point is a must and realizing the second point would make it better.

Comment: For a fine grained sentiment score you can output the softmax probabilities. This softmax probability for all classes would sum to. Most ML algotithm libraries have predict_prob similar thing can be used for ML. Not sure on what do you mean when you say "I want to get sentiment score under unsupervised learning" Please elaborate

Comment: @Ashwiniku918 Thank you for your reply. I want to use Reuters news dataset and get the sentiment score of the news every day but its sentiment is unlabelled.
I now plan to train a sentiment classification model on a large text dataset labelled with sentiment first, and then fine-tune it on a small news dataset (from kaggle), and finally use the model on Reuters news dataset.